# TCPDF generating a very large format (HUGE) page layout

Tags: tcpdf

I need to print an organigram of a large corporation with php/MySQL. The organigram will be boxes with peoples names in them, and there are just over 200. The page will be very wide and long. I want to be able to set the page size to something like 90 inches high by 300 inches wide (The PDF will be printed on an eco-plotter which is usually used to print architectural plans, but can be used to make huge black and white wall posters. I have done this many times using PageMaker/InDesign but never with php). Is it possible to do this with TCPDF and if yes how? If no, any suggestions of how I can do this in php?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TCPDF is perfectly capable of generating very large PDF documents.  If you're rendering a lot of elements, it would likely be a good idea to make sure you have a high memory limit.

I created an example here: [Example large format PDF](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rrbits/example_large.pdf)

The key part is providing your own custom page size. Here's what I used in the script that generated this example:

```
// create new PDF document, I set landscape, 
// inches for units, 300 wide and 90 deep
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'in', array(300,90), true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

The rendering part is, of course, then entirely up to you. I just had some fun with some bezier curves and cells with borders set.

```
//Line from Dot to Tiny
$pdf->Curve(50, 30, 50 + $offsetx, 30, 50 + $offsetx + 1 , 20 + $offsety_down, 
60, 20, null, $style);
$pdf->SetXY(60, 20);
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Tiny', 1, 1, 'TLRB', 0, '', 1, 'C', 'C');
```

---

If you want to use points for working with your document (which I'd suggest it over inches - it's real easy to accidentally make 1 inch thick lines and such) pass something like the following to the constructor:

**Note: points are a physical unit of measure equal to 1/72 of an inch. This is not specifying rendering resolution but the actual physical size of the document. For line definitions you can use partial numbers for your physical units. For example: 0.75 to specify 3/4 of a point.**

```
// create new PDF document, I set landscape, 
// pt for units, 300 wide and 90 deep, 72 points per inch.
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'pt', array(300*72,90*72), true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

TCPDF will work with several different types of units. Another option is millimeters, for instance. Methods like `SetXY` and `Curve` and so on will then use whatever page unit you had set here.

Comment: I used inches here, but you can use others. In one of my tests I used millimeters. I just got a little tired of doing math to try different sizes by the time I made the final example.  So, that tells TCPDF to use inches as the page unit and then to make the page 300 inches wide and 90 inches tall.

Comment: Two caveats to be aware of: 1 - setting the page unit to inches means that all the units for things like line styles and such will be in inches. For an actual production script, it would probably make more sense to use points to define the page size.
2: Font size is always specified in points, no matter the page unit.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So now, how do you set it to points, instead of inches?

Comment: Use pt for units, and then multiply both numbers by 72.

Comment: So just to be clear, the resolution of the PDF document will be 72dpi? So if I want maximum resolution, like for example, 4000 dpi, I would multiply by 4000. I am right?

Comment: PDF documents generated this way are vectors. At print time you'd set the print resolution. Because of this, you don't need to worry about resolution at instantiation time. Just specify everything in sensible physical units. Only time you'd really deal with that is in instances where you rasterize elements or include elements that are already raster themselves. The comment section isn't really for in-depth discussion. We should probably move this to chat if you have more questions.